# Recursive iteration of a function getting stack overflows

Tags: recursion, maxima

I'm trying to write a Maxima function that iterates another function provided as an argument. The goal is basically...

```
iter(f,0) ........ gives the identity function lambda([x],x)
iter(f,1) ........ gives f
iter(f,2) ........ gives lambda([x],f(f(x))
iter(f,3) ........ gives lambda([x],f(f(f(x)))
```

The reason is trying to figure out how an iterated polynomial behaves - similar to the Robert May population equation, but a different polynomial.

Anyway, I'm very new to Maxima (at least to things that seem more like simple programming than just asking for a solution) and after some time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I think I've eliminated all silly mistakes and I must have a more fundamental misunderstanding of how Maxima works.

What I have...

```
iter(f,n) := if is (n=0)
  then lambda ([x], x)
  else block ([n2: floor (n/2),
               nr: is (n2*2#n),
               ff: iter (f,n2) ], if nr then lambda ([x],f(ff(ff(x))))
                                        else lambda ([x],  ff(ff(x)) ));
```

Maxima accepts this. Now as a simple example function to iterate...

```
inc(x):=x+1;
```

And some tests - first the base case...

```
iter(inc,0);
```

That works - it gives `lambda([x],x)` as expected. Next, "iterating" one time...

```
iter(inc,1);
```

I'm expecting something equivalent to `inc`, but because of the way this is written, more like `lambda([x],inc(identity(identity(x)))` but with more clutter. What I'm actually getting is a stack overflow...

```
Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
Control stack exhausted (no more space for function call frames).
This is probably due to heavily nested or infinitely recursive function
calls, or a tail call that SBCL cannot or has not optimized away.
...
```

I can't see why the `is (n=0)` base-case check would fail to spot that in the recursive call, so I can't see why this `iter` function would be entered more than twice for `n=1` - it seems pretty extreme for that the exhaust the stack.

Of course once I have the basic idea working I'll probably special-case `n=1` as effectively another base case for efficiency (a less cluttered resulting function definition) and add more checks, but I just want something that doesn't stack-overflow in trivial cases for now.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. It's necessary to substitute into the body of `lambda` since the body is not evaluated -- I guess you have encountered this important point already.

```
(%i3) iter(f, n) := if n = 0 then identity elseif n = 1 then f
            else subst([ff = iter(f, n - 1),'f = f],
                       lambda([x], f(ff(x)))) $
(%i4) iter(inc, 0);
(%o4)                       identity
(%i5) iter(inc, 1);
(%o5)                          inc
(%i6) iter(inc, 2);
(%o6)               lambda([x], inc(inc(x)))
(%i7) iter(inc, 3);
(%o7)             lambda([x], inc(inc(inc(x))))
(%i8) iter(inc, 4);
(%o8)          lambda([x], inc(inc(inc(inc(x)))))
(%i9) inc(u) := u + 1 $
(%i10) iter(inc, 4);
(%o10)               lambda([x], inc(x + 3))
(%i11) %(10);
(%o11)                         14
(%i12) makelist (iter(cos, k), k, 0, 10);
(%o12) [identity, cos, lambda([x], cos(cos(x))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(x)))), lambda([x], 
cos(cos(cos(cos(x))))), lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x)))))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x))))))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x)))))))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x))))))))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x)))))))))), 
lambda([x], cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(cos(x)))))))))))]
(%i13) map (lambda([f], f(0.1)), %);
(%o13) [0.1, 0.9950041652780257, 0.5444993958277886, 
0.8553867058793604, 0.6559266636704799, 0.7924831019448093, 
0.7020792679906703, 0.7635010336918854, 0.7224196362389732, 
0.7502080588752906, 0.731547032044224]
```

Maxima is almost good at stuff like this -- since it is built on top of Lisp, the right conceptual elements are present. However, the lack of lexical scope is a serious problem when working on problems like this, because it means that when you refer to `f` within a function definition, it is the same `f` which might exist outside of it. When the solution depends on carefully distinguishing which `f` you mean, that's a problem.

Anyway as it stands I hope this solution is useful to you in some way.

Comment: OK, interesting. You're not doing the divide-and-conquer that I'm doing, but I was only doing that from habit - I doubt there's a performance benefit when the real costs are hidden in Maximas own function/expression manipulations as those expressions rapidly get bigger. Your approach certainly wins on simplicity and not needing those nested `block` expressions.

Comment: BTW - thanks for the quick list handling 101

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, after a moment of inspiration, I tried the following in Maxima...

```
block([a:1,b:a],b);
```

This gave me `a` where I was expecting `1`, which suggests that the `b:a` variable definition cannot see the `a:1` variable definition earlier in the same block. I had assumed that later variable definitions in a `block` would be able to see earlier definitions, and that affects two variable definitions in my `iter` function - in particular, `iter (f,n2)` cannot see the definition of `n2` which breaks the base-case check in the recursion.

What I have now (WARNING - NOT A WORKING SOLUTION) is...

```
iter(f,n) := if is (n=0)
  then lambda ([x], x)
  else block ([n2: floor (n/2)],
           block ([g: iter (f,n2)],
               if is (n2*2#n) then lambda ([x],f(g(g(x))))
                              else lambda ([x],  g(g(x)) )));
```

I'm nesting one block inside another so that the later variable definition can see the earlier one. There is no `nr` (n was rounded?) variable, though TBH keeping that wouldn't have required a third nested block. I replaced `ff` with `g` at some point.

This solves the stack overflow issue - the base case of the recursion seems to be handled correctly now.

This still isn't working - it seems like the references to `g` now cannot see the definition of `g` for some reason.

```
iter(inc,0) ................. lambda([x],x)
iter(inc,1) ................. lambda([x],f(g(g(x))))
iter(inc,2) ................. lambda([x],g(g(x)))
...
```

When the recursive half-size iteration `g` is needed, for some reason it's not substituted. Also noticable - neither is `f` substituted.

As a best guess, this is probably due to the function calls being by-name in the generated lambda, and due to nothing forcing them to be substituted in or forcing the overall expression to be simplified.

(update - [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164323/maxima-how-to-replace-variables-in-equations) suggests I've understood the problem, but the solution doesn't appear to work in my case - what I'm trying to substitute is referenced via a variable no matter what.)

But it's also a different question (it's not a recursion/stack overflow issue) so I'll come back and ask another question if I can't figure it out. I'll also add a working solution here if/when I figure it out.

---

I tried a few more approaches using `subst` and the double-quote notation, but Maxima stubbornly kept referring to `f` and `g` by name. After a little thought, I switched approach - instead of generating a function, generate an expression. The working result is...

```
iter(v,e,n) := if is (n=0)
  then ''v
  else block ([n2: floor (n/2)],
           block ([g: iter (v,e,n2)],
               block ([gg: subst([''v=g], g)],
                   if is (n2*2#n) then subst([''v=e], gg)
                                  else gg                )));
```

The three nested `block` expressions are annoying - I'm probably still missing something that's obvious to anyone with any Maxima experience. Also, this is fragile - it probably needs some parameter checks, but not on every recursive call. Finally, it doesn't simplify result - it just builds an expression by applying direct substitution into itself.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do everything with expressions?

```
(%i1) iter(e, n):= block([ans: e], thru n - 1 do ans: subst('x = e, ans), ans) $

(%i2) iter(x^2 + x, 1);
                                     2
(%o2)                               x  + x
(%i3) iter(x^2 + x, 2);
                                2     2    2
(%o3)                         (x  + x)  + x  + x
(%i4) iter(x^2 + x, 3);
                     2     2    2     2     2     2    2
(%o4)             ((x  + x)  + x  + x)  + (x  + x)  + x  + x
```

You can define a function at the end:

```
(%i5) define(g(x), iter(x^2 + x, 3));
```